# Reusing connection manager from SSIS script task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

In my SSIS package, I created [ADO connection manager](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ado-net-connection-manager-in-ssis/), so I have `MyAdoManager.conmgr` that has underlying connection named `MyServerName.MyDbName`.

Now, I'm trying to [use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11867831/437393) in the `Script Task` the way it's described in [some](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2011/05/use-connections-properly-in-ssis-script.html) manuals.

```
ConnectionManager cm;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlComm;

cm = Dts.Connections["MyAdoManager.conmgr"]; // also tried "MyServerName.MyDbName"

sqlConn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
sqlComm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable", sqlConn);
sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

cm.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn);
```

**The issue**

After executing package, I always get an exception "Connection not found". How do I get access to the connection used by existing connection manager?

What connection name should I use here `cm = Dts.Connections["..."]`?

Also, I saw some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097343/437393) that I need connection manager to the script box, but I don't have any connection related settings in the script editor in my SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of solved. Undocumented feature. Script task can access connection in the connection manager only if they have the same name.

Once I renamed connection manager from `MyAdoManager.conmgr` back to `MyServerName.MyDbName.conmgr` and it matched with the connection name `MyServerName.MyDbName` I was able to use it in the Script Task.